Is <PackageName>_FOUND variable ALWAYS set by CMake's find_package?
I've heard some people claim that if you run a find_package(<PackageName>_FOUND) in your CMakeLists.txt, it is (just like <PackageName>_INCLUDE_DIRS) at the disposal of the package maintainer how the result variable is named. Others claim that it is guaranteed to be <PackageName>_FOUND.
In the documentation we read:

The primary task of a find module is to determine whether a package is available, set the _FOUND variable to reflect this and provide any variables, macros and imported targets required to use the package. A find module is useful in cases where an upstream library does not provide a config file package.

So this sounds very much like <PackageName>_FOUND is definitely set by the  find module itself, always and not dependent on the Find<PackageName>.cmake file.
Since still people contradict themselves on this point, I'm not interested in someone linking to another mere opinion on this matter.
This question is looking for an authoritative answer, or an example that proves it one way or the other.

"So this sounds very much like <PackageName>_FOUND is definitely set by the find module itself, always and not dependent on the Find<PackageName>.cmake file." - A "find module" denotes "Find<PackageName>.cmake file". And a responsibility of that file is to set <PackageName>_FOUND variable.

Indeed, nothing is guaranteed as the only thing find_package does is look for and include/process a CMake configuration file. It's up to the author of this (usually generated) file to make sure it sets necessary variables correctly so that they could be used. Any variables that won't ever be used don't need to be set.
CMake isn't some kind of authority that makes sure all packages are produced correctly, this is just a standard saying how to name your variables for compatibility with other CMake functionality. If you don't adhere to it, you'll need to deal with any problems arising from that, but if you think you know what you're doing, you don't have to.
A common component of a Find<PackageName>.cmake is find_package_handle_standard_args() (source), which is responsible for setting the <PackageName>_FOUND variable. Therefore you don't have to directly set it yourself. If you don't do anything, it'll be missing and that can cause trouble later, but it's still fine.
In short the answer is: nothing is truly required. Your Find<PackageName>.cmake can be literally empty. It will be useless, but won't result in an error as long as it's on CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.
Of course, thanks to all the helper functions and generators, it's actually quite difficult to not set basic variables.
